# Send PCAP un-capture-able packets to local sockets

Tags: linux, networking, pcap, tcpdump, libpcap

See, I have to send packets to local sockets based on the packets I captured through PCAP, and I don't want PCAP to capture these new generated packets.

Though It's possible to leave these packets with dedicated filter rules, I think it's good to know if it's possible to send packets to local sockets with these packets completely invisible to PCAP, for efficiency.

PS. Not sure if it's proper to post this question here, as it seems like I can also post it into the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or SuperUser, but I'm sure it's about programming.

Comment: Pcap will only see what goes on the wire. It won't see traffic to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @EJP Seems like tcpdump can capture local traffic.

Comment: Are you sniffing all packets with pcap or can you set a filter to avoid certain packets?

Comment: @rodolk I'm sniffing all packets. EJP reminded me that I can just capture packets on just necessary devs, so these local packets are equally invisible to PCAP.